# How to set CLANGS in a cmake cache file?

Tags: cmake

I'm want to compile TDengine with cmake and clang, what's the best practise to manage different compiler path and cflags/cxxflags options for gcc or clang?

My cache file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER CACHE FILEPATH /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER CACHE FILEPATH /usr/bin/clang++)
set(CFLAGS "-Wno-error=incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-error=implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-error=implicit-const-int-float-conversion")
```

Seems CFLAGS not passed to compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got this `CFLAG` part from a makefile where it was used somewhere. In cmake `CFLAG` has no specific relevance, see [the list of cmake variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) (doesn't list it).

The imho best way to organize these kind of settings is using [toolchain files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) containing the compiler specific info.

**toolchains/clang.cmake**

```
# clang toolchain

#modified example for cross compiling for raspbery from the cmake documentation

#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME ...)
#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ...)

#set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ...)
#set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX ...)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)

#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ...)
#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ...)
#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ...)
#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ...)

# set initial compile flags
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT -Wno-error=incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-error=implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-error=implicit-const-int-float-conversion)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT}) # use the same flags for C++?
```

Note that several `set()` commands are commented out, since they are only required, if you need to crosscompile and specifying them would limit some cmake features.

**toolchains/gnu.cmake**

```
# gnu toolchain

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)

# different compiler flags here?
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT -Wno-error=incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-error=implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-error=implicit-const-int-float-conversion)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT}) # use the same flags for C++?
```

This allows you to use the `-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchains/clang.cmake` option to specify that clang should be used with the project you're configuring.

You could also specify this via [`CMakePresets.json` file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) which allows you to define defaults for several settings including toolchain file and you just need the `--preset=my-preset-name` option, which could be convenient, if you want to share the project...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. It saves my life.